# Dynamically adding TextView to ScrollView on Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I try to make a ScrollView to act like a ListView. So every row will be a TextView added dynamically.  but the program crashes. I have a ScrollView inside a LinearLayout. What i do wrong? Thanks.

Here is my code

```
                        scroll = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
                    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);
                    layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    TextView[] tx = new TextView[10];
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                        tx[i] = new TextView(HelloWorldActivity.this);
                        tx[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                    tx[i].setText("This is the textviewNo" + i);
                    layout.addView(tx[i]);
                    }

                    scroll.addView(layout);
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timeflag"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="50sp" 
    android:gravity="center"/>



<Button
    android:id="@+id/pause"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/timeflag"
    android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
    android:text="Start" />


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pause"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please add your logcat errors. "the program crashes" is too vague.

Answer (score 3):

A scrollView Can only have one child. If you try to add more than 1 child to the scroll view then it will crash. You should have the LinearLayout inside of the scrollview and then dynamically add textViews to the linear layout.

Comment: Good eye, but the author is adding a LinearLayout as the ScrollView's child, `scroll.addView(layout);` In this case the child is also the ScrollView's parent, which is wrong. (What's that song from Deliverance?)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add `LinearLayout1` as its own child's child (being your own grandfather, is a confusing notion).

Change you XML around like this:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pause"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: +1 yes LinearLayout1 is already added in xml and you are again adding it in java (re-parenting it)......

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add views to a scrollview. You can only add them to a viewgroup, like linear or relativelayout.

It is not exactly clear what you are trying to achieve, but what is wrong with using a listview for this? You could set a max height on the listview. Or you could try wdziemia's suggestion